# Пытаюсь вывести select список из БД.Что нужно дописать что бы список вывелся?

Tags: php, база-данных

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Личный кабинет</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <div><?php echo "Привет, ".$_SESSION['user'][1]; ?> | <a href="index.php?link=logout">Выйти</a>
    </div>
    <h3>Создание заявки</h3>
    <form  method="post">
    <p><select size="3" name="nameselect" multiple>
        <option value="Тест1">Тест1</option>
        <option value="Тест2">Тест2</option>
        <option value="Тест3">Тест3</option>
       </select></p>
       <p><input type="submit" name="do-len"value="Отправить"></p>
       </form>
       <h3>Просмотр своих записей на курсы</h3>
      <?php
    $sql = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `len` = '$len'");
$result = $sql->fetch_all();
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112192/discussion-on-question-by-----select----).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

получить записи можно так:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `len` = '$len'");
```

Однако не рекомендуется напрямую использовать переменные в запросе, вместо этого использовать [подготавливаемые запросы](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

```
// получаете результат в виде ассоциативного массива
// где ключи - имена полей таблицы
$result = $sql->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

// используете как угодно. Для просмотра результатов можете воспользоваться одной из конструкций:
var_dump($result);
echo '<pre>'.print_r($result, true).'</pre>';

// вывести все `len` можете примерно так:
foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo '<p>'.$row['len'].'</p>';
}
```

Comment: mysqli_stmt_bind_param

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov это вы к чему?

Comment: К тому, что данные в запрос не вклеивают а bind-ят, или хоть проверяют.
Я понимаю, что у автора жесть через строчку, но вы же отвечаете.

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov да, не подумал, признаться. А как в таких случаях быть? Не отвечать вообще, или отвечать и делать пояснения?

Comment: я бы ответил так, чтоб дырки не оставалось

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов я не понимаю что произошло вчера получилось вывести var_dump($result); сегодня же он просто выводит массив (0) {}.Что произошло в чем ошибка?

Comment: $sql = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `len` = '$len'");
$result = $sql->fetch_all();
var_dump($result);

Comment: Да кто ж его знает. Я прошу прощения, но вы хоть пытаетесь понять, что пишете? Ну ведь сейчас можно самому разобраться. Почему массив пустой (0) ? Наверное, потому, что запрос к бд не вернул ни одной записи. Почему он не вернул записи? Потому что в бд нет записей с условием, которое вы пишете. Какое условие? - WHERE len = $len. Посмотрите перед запросом, что у вас в переменной. `var_dump($len);` и посмотрите в базе, есть ли реально такие записи.

Answer (score 0):

Выглядит, как хорошая статья с примерами на вашу тему:

https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli_examples/prepared_select

Рассказывается, как подготовить и запустить SQL выражение, и как отобразить его результат.

Пример из статьи:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=?"; // SQL with parameters
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); 
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result(); // get the mysqli result
$data = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach($data as $row): ?>
        <li><?= $row['name'] ?></li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: сложновато все написано обьектно ор программированием.таким стилем я писать не привык)

Comment: считайте, что до стрелки первый аргумент, и всё. Вам же не компонентную архитектуру свою придумывать тут. И статью смотрите, там всё подробно с полезными советами.

Comment: А то у вас программа с дырой в безопасности `'$len'"`.
И еще логаут по ссылке может не сработать. И там кучу еще выровнять можно.

Comment: мне пока и так пойдет через 5 дней сдавать отчет а я тут застрял)и моим проверяющим безопасность не главное им главное что бы  я выполнил задачу)

Comment: Если ответ полезен -- принимай галочкой

Comment: мой вопрос остался открытым)

Comment: И что тебе мешает его закрыть

Comment: чувак я прошу что бы мне показали почему не работает код?что то может дописать надо?а ты мне куча всего не по делу накидал,посмотри как мне отвечали на мои вопросы другие вот они рил мне помогли,а то что ты мне накидал и на учебе достаточно накидывают...сори без обид)